# Changing Development environment of Asp.net 2.0 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: development-environment

I was developing an application of asp.net 2.0 in 32 bit machine but now I have 64 bit platform for the same application. I am not able to debug my code in 64 bit machine.

Ny1 Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you recompiled the application?

2) If you have try changing the 'Platform Target', in Project Properties -> Build -> Platform Target to "Any CPU" or "x64".

3) It would be worth reading the MSDN Article on [Migrating 32-bit managed code to 64-bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx#64mig_topic6) to ensure you don't have any interop/serialization/etc.. issues to deal with, aswell as Scott's [blog article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx) on the subject.